# A proposition of relative interior point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

One proposition from `Convex Optimization Algorithm p.473`:

1. $X$ is a nonempty convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$
2. $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a concave function
3. $X^*=\bigg\{x^* \in X  \ \ | \ \ f(x^*) = \underset{x\in X}{\text{inf}}f(x)\bigg\}$

> If $X^*$ contains a relative interior point of $X$, then $f$ must be constant over $X$, i.e., $X^*=X$

I cannot quite understand the part in yellow. I know the definition of interior point, but I do not know how to use it in this proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x \in \mathrm{ri}(X) \cap X^*$ and $y \in X$ satisfied $f(y) > f(x)$.

Because $X$ is convex, $\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y \in X$ for all $\lambda \in [0, 1]$. But, since $x$ is in the relative interior of $X$, we can always go a little bit further, that is, for some $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y \in X$ for all $\lambda \in [0, 1 + \varepsilon]$. In particular, we have $z = (1 + \varepsilon)x - \varepsilon y \in X$. Then,
$$\frac{1}{1 + \varepsilon}z + \frac{\varepsilon}{1 + \varepsilon}y = x.$$
Applying the concavity of $f$,
$$f(x) \ge \frac{1}{1 + \varepsilon}f(z) + \frac{\varepsilon}{1 + \varepsilon}f(y).$$
But $x$ minimises $f$ over $X$, so $f(z) \ge f(x)$. We have assumed $f(y) > f(x)$, so
$$f(x) \ge \frac{1}{1 + \varepsilon}f(z) + \frac{\varepsilon}{1 + \varepsilon}f(y) > \frac{1}{1 + \varepsilon}f(x) + \frac{\varepsilon}{1 + \varepsilon}f(x) = f(x).$$
This implies $f(x) > f(x)$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

i think the line number 3, says that the optimal point must be belonged to interior points of function f. in fact, if the function f be concave then, the infimum of the interior point is the optimum point (the maximum value).